# select as many rows as possible, to guarantee the item density of each column

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have a 0-1 matrix, like:

```
0, 1, 1, 1, 1 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0
```

The goal is to select as many rows as possible from this matrix, to form a new matrix, and guarantee that in the new matrix, each column contains not-less-than 80% of `1`.

For example to the above matrix, the result will be:

```
0, 1, 1, 1, 1 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0
```

Greedy algorithm doesn't work for this problem obviously, neither does a normal DP as I see.

In the real problem, the matrix will have about 7000 rows and 100 columns. And since there would be a few all-1 rows, so there will always exist at least one solution.

Could anyone help to inspire me? Thanks.

Comment: Looks NP-hard to me. I would go for some kind of approximation scheme

Comment: Sounds similar to subset sum and integer linear programming to me. On the other hand, DP might help; could you show what you tried in terms of DP?

Comment: @G.Bach I have thought of DP and also tried to reduce the practical problem to a DP-able problem. But currently I'm almost sure, if not definitely, that DP won't help :-(

Comment: One way would be a bounded search starting with the most likely candidates and working down the list to see which other rows you can add.

Initially sort the rows by the number of bits set, then check each row in turn to see if it can be added to the solution without breaking the constraint. Keep running down the list of rows yet to be added until you have run down the list without adding a new row to the solution. This will produce one of the solutions.

Comment: If you wanted to try a second pass, then count up the bits set in each column, and weight the score of each row so those with bits set where the count is lower rank higher (to even out the percentages).

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of simplistic answer:

(simplistic because the search is "timid" - it only takes one step before evaluating if the state is acceptable, it doesn't re-prioritise to look for rows that will help the columns reaching 80% quicker.

## code.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
data = [
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1 ],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0 ]
]

# array with blocks of different average densities
data = 990.times.collect do
         limit = rand(1000)
         100.times.collect do
          rand(1000) <= limit ? 1 : 0
        end
      end + 10.times.collect { 100.times.collect { 1 } }

#puts "data = #{data.inspect}"

def sum(list)
  list.inject(0){|res,v| res + v}
end

def column_percent(array)
  multiplier = 100.0 / array.count
  array.transpose.collect{|column| sum(column) * multiplier}
end

sorted_data = data.sort{|a,b| sum(b) <=> sum(a)}

#puts sorted_data.inspect
puts "Data percentages: #{column_percent(data).inspect}"
puts "Average over data: #{column_percent(data).min.inspect}"


solution = [ ]
consider = sorted_data
discarded = [ ]
loops = 0
done_something = true
achieved = [ ]
while (done_something)
  loops += 1
  done_something = false
  while (!consider.empty?)
    row = consider.shift
    #puts "Considerring: #{row.inspect}"
    if column_percent(solution + [ row ]).min >= 80.0
      done_something = true
      solution.push row
    else
      discarded.push row
    end
  end
  achieved << solution.count
  consider = discarded
  discarded = [ ]
end

puts "solution: #{solution.inspect}" if solution.count < 10
puts "solution.percents = #{column_percent(solution).inspect}"
puts "min solution.percents = #{column_percent(solution).min.inspect}"
puts "solution has #{solution.count.inspect} rows"
puts "consider has #{consider.count.inspect} rows"
puts "went through #{loops} loops, achievment at end of each loop: #{achieved.inspect} rows"

exit
```

**END**

Results:

```
Data percentages: [66.66666666666667, 83.33333333333334, 83.33333333333334, 66.66666666666667, 83.33333333333334]
Average over data: 66.66666666666667
solution: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
solution.percents = [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0]
min solution.percents = 100.0
solution has 2 rows
consider has 4 rows
went through 2 loops, achievment at end of each loop: [2, 2] rows


$ time ruby code.rb # 1000 rows

Data percentages: [50.900000000000006, 48.900000000000006, 50.2, 49.7, 47.5, 50.800000000000004, 50.2, 48.900000000000006, 51.300000000000004, 49.1, 49.900000000000006, 48.7, 49.7, 48.900000000000006, 50.300000000000004, 52.400000000000006, 51.0, 49.900000000000006, 50.800000000000004, 49.6, 49.0, 50.1, 49.1, 48.7, 50.800000000000004, 49.0, 49.2, 49.900000000000006, 48.800000000000004, 50.1, 50.2, 49.6, 49.900000000000006, 50.2, 50.900000000000006, 49.2, 51.7, 49.300000000000004, 48.400000000000006, 49.400000000000006, 49.5, 49.6, 47.7, 50.0, 46.900000000000006, 51.0, 50.0, 51.5, 50.5, 49.300000000000004, 49.1, 50.400000000000006, 47.800000000000004, 51.800000000000004, 50.2, 49.400000000000006, 49.400000000000006, 49.0, 51.5, 48.0, 53.7, 49.1, 51.300000000000004, 50.400000000000006, 50.800000000000004, 48.900000000000006, 50.6, 47.0, 50.300000000000004, 49.400000000000006, 50.800000000000004, 51.300000000000004, 52.900000000000006, 50.0, 51.300000000000004, 47.800000000000004, 51.300000000000004, 47.6, 49.900000000000006, 54.5, 49.5, 51.800000000000004, 50.800000000000004, 50.400000000000006, 51.0, 50.1, 47.7, 49.6, 53.300000000000004, 50.2, 49.7, 51.5, 47.900000000000006, 49.7, 48.0, 48.6, 49.6, 48.900000000000006, 50.1, 50.7]
Average over data: 46.900000000000006
solution.percents = [84.02366863905326, 83.13609467455622, 85.50295857988166, 81.65680473372781, 80.17751479289942, 82.54437869822486, 83.13609467455622, 81.95266272189349, 82.54437869822486, 80.4733727810651, 87.27810650887574, 82.84023668639054, 83.4319526627219, 82.54437869822486, 80.76923076923077, 84.31952662721893, 81.36094674556213, 85.79881656804734, 82.24852071005917, 83.72781065088758, 81.65680473372781, 82.24852071005917, 80.76923076923077, 82.54437869822486, 85.20710059171599, 83.72781065088758, 80.17751479289942, 83.72781065088758, 82.84023668639054, 81.95266272189349, 84.61538461538461, 80.17751479289942, 81.95266272189349, 81.36094674556213, 84.02366863905326, 84.61538461538461, 84.02366863905326, 83.72781065088758, 82.24852071005917, 84.31952662721893, 84.02366863905326, 84.02366863905326, 80.17751479289942, 82.84023668639054, 80.4733727810651, 82.84023668639054, 83.13609467455622, 82.84023668639054, 80.17751479289942, 80.17751479289942, 82.84023668639054, 83.72781065088758, 80.17751479289942, 81.95266272189349, 81.95266272189349, 82.84023668639054, 80.76923076923077, 81.95266272189349, 81.95266272189349, 82.84023668639054, 85.20710059171599, 83.4319526627219, 83.72781065088758, 80.17751479289942, 84.31952662721893, 82.54437869822486, 86.09467455621302, 81.95266272189349, 82.54437869822486, 81.95266272189349, 81.95266272189349, 83.72781065088758, 83.4319526627219, 84.61538461538461, 86.68639053254438, 81.06508875739645, 83.4319526627219, 80.76923076923077, 80.76923076923077, 85.79881656804734, 82.84023668639054, 85.79881656804734, 84.31952662721893, 82.24852071005917, 84.02366863905326, 80.76923076923077, 80.17751479289942, 84.9112426035503, 83.72781065088758, 84.61538461538461, 83.13609467455622, 84.61538461538461, 84.61538461538461, 82.54437869822486, 80.76923076923077, 82.84023668639054, 80.4733727810651, 80.17751479289942, 82.84023668639054, 80.17751479289942]
min solution.percents = 80.17751479289942
solution has 338 rows
consider has 662 rows
went through 3 loops, achievment at end of each loop: [337, 338, 338] rows

real    0m7.588s
user    0m7.435s
sys 0m0.142s
```

Time for 7000 random rows:

achieved: 2742
Accepted: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
achieved: 2743
achieved: 2743
solution.percents = [81.18847976667881, 80.42289464090412, 81.00619759387531, 80.93328472475392, 80.67808968282901, 80.38643820634341, 81.22493620123952, 81.55304411228582, 81.22493620123952, 80.20415603353992, 80.45935107546481, 81.22493620123952, 80.56872037914691, 80.02187386073642, 81.15202333211812, 82.39154210718192, 80.02187386073642, 80.24061246810062, 81.26139263580022, 80.38643820634341, 80.02187386073642, 80.27706890266131, 80.16769959897921, 81.00619759387531, 80.49580751002551, 81.37076193948232, 81.69886985052861, 80.24061246810062, 81.00619759387531, 80.34998177178271, 80.20415603353992, 81.69886985052861, 81.51658767772511, 80.64163324826832, 80.02187386073642, 80.02187386073642, 80.02187386073642, 80.02187386073642, 80.34998177178271, 80.27706890266131, 80.02187386073642, 80.16769959897921, 80.82391542107182, 81.29784907036091, 81.77178271965002, 80.75100255195042, 81.84469558877142, 80.53226394458622, 80.02187386073642, 80.86037185563251, 80.09478672985782, 81.18847976667881, 81.15202333211812, 80.31352533722202, 82.28217280349982, 82.02697776157491, 81.48013124316441, 80.64163324826832, 80.89682829019321, 81.11556689755741, 81.26139263580022, 80.64163324826832, 80.64163324826832, 80.45935107546481, 80.86037185563251, 80.31352533722202, 80.05833029529711, 81.40721837404301, 81.00619759387531, 81.77178271965002, 80.96974115931461, 81.22493620123952, 81.37076193948232, 80.49580751002551, 80.05833029529711, 80.89682829019321, 81.44367480860372, 80.02187386073642, 80.02187386073642, 81.55304411228582, 80.67808968282901, 80.49580751002551, 81.26139263580022, 80.02187386073642, 80.27706890266131, 80.42289464090412, 80.45935107546481, 81.55304411228582, 81.77178271965002, 80.45935107546481, 81.73532628508931, 80.75100255195042, 83.04775792927451, 80.45935107546481, 80.02187386073642, 80.02187386073642, 81.04265402843602, 81.51658767772511, 80.89682829019321, 81.58950054684651]
min solution.percents = 80.02187386073642
solution has 2743 rows
consider has 4267 rows
went through 3 loops, achievment at end of each loop: [2742, 2743, 2743] rows

real    5m57.637s
user    5m57.446s
sys 0m0.335s

Comment: With this as a starting point, you can decide how much extra time you want to searching for a better solution. Alternative starting points would include starting with all rows selected and trying to find the minimum rows to be eliminated, possibly giving more consideration to rows with zeros in the columns with the worst score.